# Placing an element in a random position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to place an element in a random position with this code, but it just places the element on the top of my container element. What am I doing wrong?

```
   create: function(){

    console.log("cone created");

    var el =  document.createElement('div');
    el.classList.add('cone');

    this.container.appendChild(el);

    this.el = el;

    this.x = Math.random () * canvas.innerWidth + 'px';
    this.y = Math.random () * canvas.innerHeight + 'px';

    },
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually does something with `this.x` and `this.y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe inserting `div` with inline css can handle this.

I wrote a sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sqrPixel = 10;

  var posX = 30;
  var posY = 100;

  $('body').append('<div style="background: #ccc; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000; position: absolute; width: ' + sqrPixel + 'px; height: ' + sqrPixel + 'px; left: ' + posX + '; top: ' + posY + ';"></div>');
});
```

I append the squares to the `body`. Change it if you want. You can set `posX` and `posY` randomly.

I know it looks a bit messy but at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming "canvas" isn't really a canvas, it's just a `<div>`.

In that case, you need to do several things:

- Ensure your container has `position:relative`
- Ensure your container's children have `position:absolute`
- Add `el.style.left = this.x; el.style.top = this.y;` to actually position the element